# How to install Microsoft Mouse in Macbook Pro running OSX

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, installation, drivers, mouse

I bought a Microsoft Mouse and am trying to install the drivers on the CD. The problem is that when I run the installer it says a newer version of the software is already on the hard disk so it can't install.

This can't be true though, because the software connects to the internet and checks for a newer version, which it doesn't find, meaning that it is the newest version.

I have ran the Intellipoint Uninstaller to remove the old drivers from my system, and removed the entries in the System Preferences panel. Still, the system thinks the software is still on the system.

How can I get this installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing IntelliPoint:
http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/drivers/intellipointandintellitypepro.html

Answer (score 3):

> How to install Microsoft Mouse in Macbook Pro running OSX

1. Plug the mouse.
2. Use it.

I don't think you need a driver for a mouse. It is supported by default.

Comment: That's the nice thing about Mac's, no drivers.

Comment: Yes, the mouse works, but only partially. This mouse has five buttons, and two of these buttons are not functioning in OSX. It needs the software on the CD that came with it to be installed in order to enable these two extra buttons.

Comment: @Linux Jedi: you should try USB Overdrive (http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html)